# Zerorpc throwing error on recv

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, zeromq, zerorpc

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Node.js 0.10.37 in Ubuntu 12.04 and using zerorpc to invoke python from node js.. My python runs at port 9004 and node client listens to 9004 port. While invoking a method in python from Node js i'm getting the error below:

```
ERROR:zerorpc.channel:zerorpc.ChannelMultiplexer ignoring error on recv
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/channel.py", line 79, in _channel_dispatcher 
    event = self._events.recv()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 341, in recv      
    event = Event.unpack(get_pyzmq_frame_buffer(blob))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 198, in unpack    
    unpacked_msg = unpacker.unpack()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msgpack/fallback.py", line 570, in unpack  
    ret = self._fb_unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT, write_bytes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msgpack/fallback.py", line 498, in _fb_unpack
    typ, n, obj = self._read_header(execute, write_bytes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msgpack/fallback.py", line 347, in _read_header
    b = ord(c)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but memoryview found
```

My Node.js client side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var zerorpc = require('zerorpc');
var router = express.Router();

var client = new zerorpc.Client({timeout:30, heartbeatInterval:30000});
client.connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:9004");

router.post('/validateUser/', function(req, res, next){
    var user_name = req.body.user_name;
    client.invoke("validate_user", user_name, function(request, response, more){
        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

My Python code:

```
import zerorpc
class User():

    def validate_user(self, user_name):
        print user_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = User()
    s = zerorpc.Server(obj)
    s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:9004")
    s.run()
```

Even the print statement in python is not getting executed.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling zerorpc and zmq. But still the same error, the same code was working in a different Ubuntu machine with same architecture.

Comment: interesting, it looks like you are using the python fallback of msgpack, which I have honestly never tested. This might explain the problem: the native version expects a memoryview or a buffer (depending of the version of Python), but the python one might not :/

Comment: could you please suggest a possible fix for this error.

Comment: The same piece of code executes perfectly when using Python 2.7.5 instead of 2.7.3 in a different Ubuntu machine. Just wanted to know what might've caused the error while using Python 2.7.3

Comment: I will try to find time to reproduce the bug. of course, everything passes when I test... (https://travis-ci.org/0rpc/zerorpc-python). Can you find a way to use the native msgpack instead of the fallback on your first machine?